# Protect Jar file source code with exe file (Java)

Tags: java, jar, exe

How would I make a `.JAR` file open up when I make another file as `.EXE`?

I have tried many things, but they don't work.

I want this for another way to protect my source code. Kind of like what Minecraft does. You open a `.EXE`, and somehow the `.EXE` opens up the `.JAR` file.

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Nope, he/she is talking about `.CLASS` files, not `.JAR` files.

Comment: Try actually reading the accepted answer to that question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To convert to exe, I use [JAR2EXE](http://www.regexlab.com/en/jar2exe/).

However obfuscating your code can deter people who want to access your code. But  a determined person would still access it. You can use proguard to obfuscate your code.\

[ProGuard](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: I use Allatori. Is it worse than ProGuard?

Comment: @JavaCoder-1337 I don't know, never tried it. It seems professionally done though.

Answer (score 0):

You want something like this:

-> http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Obfuscated_code

You can access the MineCraft.jar but the code is obfuscated.

Comment: How do I make a `.EXE` launch a `.JAR`?