# How does the Jar2Exe works when Protecting Java Class files from being extracted

Tags: java, obfuscation

I want to protect my files from being extracted and my code get hacked. I saw two similar questions on SO

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9633455/how-to-protect-a-jar-file-from-being-decompiled
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7622419/protect-jar-file-source-code-with-exe-file-java
```

but these question's answers end up with using **ProGaurd**. While ProGaurd itself state that it will just try its best to obfuscate the code and doesn't guarantee 100% that the code will remain secure.

But there are softwares which convert Jar2Exe @ http://www.jar2exe.com/ which guarantees that the code will remain 100% secure. Besides JarProtector @ http://www.bfa-it.com/?lang=en&id=products/jarprotector

If someone is guaranteeing that our class files will remain secure then that means there is surely a way out but what is that technique they would be using to protect our Class files. I know that you can only guess but what would you best guess so we can protect our applications before we hand our Life-Efforted application to clients?

Comment: There is no such thing as 100% secure code.

Comment: @icza you can see at there website, they guarrantee it and when you try their software, you can see when the application is converted with their softwares, we cannot extract or get our class files.

Answer (score 1):

First of all : there is no such thing as "100% secure".

Now : all of these apps simply wrap your jarfiles into machine-code, in fact they simply encapsulate it. Maybe some of them also obfuscate the jarfile in some way but the problem is only postponed : once an attacker gets rid of the encapsulation your java-code will be visible, readable.

Encapsulating jarfiles is ... no security at all, its quite easy to spot your jarfile inside of the machine-code if you're a skilled cracker. Obfuscating your java-code AND encapsulating it, on the other hand may very well grant you SOME security since obfuscation can be really complicated to crack.

Rest assured : it was never possible to make your application "secure", everyone on the planet can only take a few steps to make it harder to crack it.

Comment: What else would you suggest besides Obfuscating the code to protect our Classes? Or what do you do to secure your application?

Comment: there is nothing else you can do, except for switching to a language in which you are able to generate machine-code, but : like i already said, even that will only postpone the problem.