# Secure Java Program from being decompiled

Tags: java, security, proguard, obfuscation

I have investigated a lot about securing java program and found out that most of the current programs are obfuscators and just a litle harder for the hacker to hack
I finally ended up to this website 

[JarProtector](http://www.bfa-it.com/?lang=en&id=products/jarprotector)

that use secure key to encrypt the java package and has it's own program to run it
Have you ever expirienced in using it and what was your idea about it

THanks

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26083934/

Comment: Obfuscation can be very helpful in some way but there are another approach that involve translate the java program to a native representation. See projects like http://www.excelsiorjet.com/ and http://www.jwrapper.com/.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as your project is written in Java it will be able to be decompiled back into java. Obfuscators and protection just delays the process of a dedicated reverse engineerer.

For example, to get back the original jar file from JarProtector all a person needs to do is to decompile JarProtector. It has to eventually extract the jar to be able to invoke it, so if you take that process and modify it you can save the extracted jar.

Answer (score 0):

I've found excelsior the best way to protect JAVA Codes